# Не работает Nuxt-приложение после генерации статического проекта

Tags: vue.js, frontend, хостинг, nuxt.js

Есть готовый проект, все работает. Хочу выложить на хостинг. Cоздала статический проект с помощью команды

```
npm run generate
```

Но теперь проект полноценно не работает, не на компе, не на хостинге - не подгружает данные которые должны получать с одного API с помощью axios. Хотя может в чем то другом дело.

В консоли ошибки что какие то js файлы не найдены.

Подскажите что делать в данной ситуации? Может ли это быть связано с тем что проект ложится не в корень на хоте, а в внутреннюю папку?

Comment: Приведите пример ошибок.

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось что проблема действительно в том что проект ложится не в корень на хоте, а в внутреннюю папку.

Чтобы все заработало надо nuxt.config.js добавить

```
router: {
        base: 'название папки'
    },
```